# Update the MSMVP links in the Ask a Question Guide

Tags: feature-request, help-center, broken-link

The current ["How do I ask a good question"](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx) page links to Jon Skeet's brilliant [article](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx) about writing the perfect question.

Unfortunately it's a link to his MS MVP blog which, as of July 2014, is [now retired](http://msmvps.com/blogs/) with blogs apparently being migrated to WordPress:

> July 2014: We've retired the Community Server Blogs and our bloggers
>   from that platform have been migrated to Wordpress blogs, including
>   previous content.

It looks like they've failed to add redirects to point to this content elsewhere and I can't actually find a (WordPress or otherwise) mirror of this blog either.

I'm also not sure if we're linking to other MSMVP blogs in any key areas but they might need changing to point to a mirror when that's up if MSMVP don't properly get redirects in place.

Comment: Related on MSE: [Is there any support for mass link editing?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/237110/167646)

Comment: I should have known that Jon Skeet would have beat me to it.

Comment: Temporary home for the post: http://blogs.msmvps.com/jonskeet/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/ but I expect it to be somewhere under jonskeet.me in the nearish future. Apologies for the disruption.

Comment: Okay, permanent home is now on http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk, and the new tinyurl is http://tinyurl.com/stack-hints instead of http://tinyurl.com/so-hints